# SAS internal Date format to yyyy-MM-dd in HIVE

Tags: sql, date, hive, date-format, typeconverter

I got SAS dataset into txt file format from client. But client didnt change the SAS date format to mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd. As SAS uses seconds since Jan 1, 1960, Date is coming like:

```
 | response_dt |
+----------------
| 19724       |
| 19673       |
| 19698       |
| 19738       |
| 19738       |
```

I want to convert this to yyyy-MM-dd format in hive. Kindly help

Comment: SAS dates are number of days since Jan 1, 1960.  Are you going to be processing this data in SAS or something else?  If you are processing in SAS and you already have these values in a SAS dataset, then you can just format response_dt ddmmyy10.

Comment: waht did you tried so far? Format, attrib, something else?

Comment: You should be able to easily find a solution to this by searching.

Comment: Apologies buddy... I want to do this in Hive

Answer (score 0):

Just read in the numbers. They are indeed days since Jan 1, 1960.

Then assign a format to them in one of the several ways you can, like

```
Data myData;
    set myData;
    format response_dt ddmmyy8.;
run;
```

If the dataset is huge, consider using `proc datasets`

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I apologies that i didnt mention it earlier...I have to do this in hive

Answer (score 0):

Sas dates are days since 1jan1960.

i made this a wiki.

Can anyone add the correct function to add days to a date in hive?

Comment: date_add('2008-12-31', 1) = '2009-01-01'  (from  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Comment: We need the inverse, something like date_diff. And you should be able to edit the answer: it is a wiki

Comment: Honestly **I** am not interested in that wiki... but the link above covers all kinds of date functions, including *date_diff*. Help yourself, and have fun  B-)

Comment: Sorry, it is data_add